# How do I import dashboards by id from grafana.com? Without json files and configMap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana, dashboard

I have a helm chart that deploys a kube-prometheus stack (prometheus, grafana, node-exporter), there are some json files (dashboards) in the grafana configuration, they are transferred to the grafana pod via configMap (common practice). I have a task to optimize this configuration to add grafana dashboards via their id from grafana.com and not to use json files (as they are very big). I know how to create a folder in grafana and specify the prometheus resource, but I don't understand how to export dashboards by id.

To create a folder I have a file (yaml) which is added via configmap to the directory /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards

```
- name: 'default'
  org_id: 1
  folder: 'my-dashboards'
  type: 'file'
  options:
    folder: '/var/lib/grafana/dashboards'
```

How to do it and in which file I need to insert this configuration to make it work. I will be grateful for help.

I tried to create configurations I found on github (dashboardProviders), but it only creates a folder (the code I specified), without dashboards

UPD: what i have now

```
apiVersion: 1
providers:
  # <string> an unique provider name. Required
  - name: 'prometheus'
    # <int> Org id. Default to 1
    orgId: 1
    # <string> name of the dashboard folder.
    folder: 'my-dashboards'
    # <string> folder UID. will be automatically generated if not specified
    folderUid: ''
    # <string> provider type. Default to 'file'
    type: file
    # <bool> disable dashboard deletion
    disableDeletion: false
    # <int> how often Grafana will scan for changed dashboards
    updateIntervalSeconds: 10
    # <bool> allow updating provisioned dashboards from the UI
    allowUiUpdates: false
    options:
      # <string, required> path to dashboard files on disk. Required when using the 'file' type
      path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
      # <bool> use folder names from filesystem to create folders in Grafana
      foldersFromFilesStructure: true

dashboards:
  default:
    MinIO:
      gnetId: 13502
      revision: 2
      datasource: prometheus
```

but it still doesn't work...why?

Comment: Please, look into [this issue](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/issues/1385#issuecomment-1148270017). I believe it has example of configuration you wanted. If it works out for you, please add an answer to your question.

Comment: @markalex Thank you, I also read this option, and yes, this is what I need, but please tell me in what file do I need to specify this configuration?

Comment: I'm not familiar with grafana in helm, but I'd guess in the same as snippet from your question.

Comment: So, I tried different places to insert this code, or part of this code, but without success :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is (or can be) a part of the [grafana helm chart](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/grafana-6.52.9/charts/grafana), from what I remember when used it in the past. That configuration needs to go into the `values.yaml` when using that helm chart.

Specifically [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/grafana-6.52.9/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L636) to enable/configure `dashboardProviders` and [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/grafana-6.52.9/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L655) to provision the `dashboard` using `dashboard id` from the grafana website.

Can also refer to some documentation [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/grafana-6.52.9/charts/grafana#import-dashboards).

Hope it helps.

Update:

Using the below config I was able to import the MinIO Dashboard (the one OP tried to import):

```
dashboardProviders:
  dashboardproviders.yaml:
   apiVersion: 1
   providers:
   - name: 'default'
     orgId: 1
     folder: 'default'
     type: file
     disableDeletion: true
     editable: true
     options:
       path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/standard

dashboards:
  default:
    MinIO:
      gnetId: 13502
      revision: 2
      datasource: prometheus
```

[image]

Ofcourse I don't have the prometheus data source, hence the warning sign(s).

Comment: Now I did exactly that, I added the code above, but there is no result :(

Comment: @kose1n Sorry, I couldn't get around earlier on this one. Updated the answer with the exact config that works for me. Hope it works for you now.

Comment: @kose1n does this work for you? if not, can you kindly post an update?